# common name not in hostname:applogin format in Quickbook merchant service

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, csr

I got this error when I want to sign my client certificate

```
ARSC262: common name not in hostname:applogin format.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

my applogin is qbms.compressportusa.com

What advice you have for me guys, i have to do this and drive me crazy...
Any advice is more than welcome thanks

Comment: if the question is out of topic as someone voted for close, can you drive me where can i post this topic? In my opinion if the question has something negative, i like to know how to improve...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSR has a CN value of:

```
 qbms.compressportusa.com/emailAddress=emilio@benamorgrp.com
```

Here's the complete line from your CSR:

```
Subject: C=US, ST=Florida, L=Miami, O=CompresSportUSA, CN=qbms.compressportusa.com/emailAddress=emilio@benamorgrp.com
```

There are two problems with this:

1. As the error says, it's not in applogin:hostname format. The CN *must* have the format applogin:hostname. e.g. it should probably be something like: "qbms.compressportusa.com:compressport.com"
2. Intuit's appreg tool is broken, and borks when you include an e-mail address. *Do not* include your e-mail address when you generate the CSR. If you enter your e-mail address, it *will not work*.

There's a bit more detail on this process and some common errors on our [QuickBooks integration development wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration).

As a side note - it's a heck of a lot easier (at least for test/development purposes) to get set up in DESKTOP mode instead of in HOSTED mode. Might be something to consider, at least until you're ready to go live.